# How do I correctly include a JSX script in my HTML?

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

Here's the problem in short: I am unable to include a JSX script in my HTML and I have no feedback on what I'm doing wrong.

This is my bare-bones HTML. I simply added an empty `test` *div* to house my React elements, included the React library scripts and my own *reactapp.jsx*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test"></div>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="./src/reactapp.jsx" type="text/jsx"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's the content of *reactapp.jsx*; all it does is display a like button that turns into the writing "You liked this." when clicked:

```
const e = React.createElement;

class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { liked: false };
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.liked)
      return "You liked this.";

    return e(
      "button",
      {onClick: () => this.setState({liked: true})},
      "Like"
    );
  }
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector("#test");
ReactDOM.render(e(LikeButton), domContainer);
```

Eveything works as long as I don't include the `type="text/jsx"` in the script tag of my HTML. As soon as I do include it, the script is ignored and the page renders as empty. I would happily go on without it but I need it in order to be able to use the JSX syntax, for instance by substituting

```
return e(
      "button",
      {onClick: () => this.setState({liked: true})},
      "Like"
    );
```

with

```
return (
      <button onClick={() => this.setState({liked: true})}>
        Like
      </button>
    );
```

Am I missing something painfully obvious?

Comment: There is a nice tutorial in React documentation on how you can add a React component to the existing website: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper

Comment: Try usual js script without type="text/jsx"

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you're advising me to drop JSX in favor of plain JS?

Comment: Try creating **reactapp.js** with the same content, add it as usual script, and see if it works